# Jquery die() method is not working on dynamically generated button in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dynamic-controls

In my web page i am creating some button dynamically and By using **ON** binding some event with the button ,on some condition i have to disable this button for that i am using die() method but it is not seems to be working on ie7 ,it is working fine on mozilla and chrome

```
$('#BtnShow').die('click');
```

Is there any wayaround for ie7?

Comment: If you're using `.on()` you should be using `.off()`, not `.die()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.off` when you bind events using `.on`.

Use `.die` when you bind events using `.live`. (Note: both `.live` and `.die` are deprecated.)

Use `.undelegate` when you bind events using `.delegate`

Use `.unbind` when you bind events using `.bind`.

**Note:** When using delegated events, make sure the selector used in `.on/.delegate/.live` matches with the selector in `.off/.undelegate/.die`

Answer (score 1):

`.die()` is deprecated now, try using `.off()`